# 2 forms or windows in one single c# project (MS visual studio)

Tags: c#, windows, forms, screen, split

Is it possible to run 2 windows in one single project? I would like to use this as my program needs to run on a projected screen, and data needs to be changed on another screen which isn't allowed to be seen by the people who are watching the projected screen.

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

When you application starts you can show mutiple forms. This is assuming you are using dual monitors, and one is mirrored on the projector.

eg:

MainForm:

```
MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
 Form1 form1 = new Form1();
 Form2 form2 = new Form2();

 form1.Show();
 //Set location to screen 1

 form2.Show();
 //Set location to screen 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you verry much !

Edit: Works like a charm after adding a new class by right clicking on the project and adding a new form. Thanks again